# Problem in creating database through code first approach

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2018. I am using a code-first approach. I have created `Tri` class:

```
namespace WebApplication3Connection
{
    public class Tri
    {
        [Key]
        public string GradeName { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and `TriContext` class:

```
public class TriContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Tri> Tris { get; set; }
}
```

Now after adding connection string in `web.config` file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TriContext" 
         connectionString="server=DESKTOP-3V101I4\SQLEXPRESS;database=Tri;Integrated Security=true; Pooling=false; timeout = 2000;"  
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My database is not getting created. While it should automatically get created after running program.

Comment: Have you created a migration? If not I would reference this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli . The migration process is what will actually create the database, as well as insert some migration files in your project to track all changes to your database.

Comment: *it should automatically get created* -- depends on the EF version.

Comment: No context type was found in the assembly 'WebApplication3Connection'. I get this error when I write migrations

Answer (score 0):

Your database will not automatically migrate, you either need to program it or do it manually. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

#### Manually

Open Package Manager Console in Visual Studio and execute these commands:

```
add-migration MyMigrationName
update-database
```

#### Programatically

You still need to create the migration manually after each change.

```
add-migration MyMigrationName
```

But the migration can be done programatically. This is interesting if you have multiple instances of the program running with multiple databases. Or have differen production and development databases for example.

```
//startup.cs:    
public void Configure(TriContext triContext) {
  triContext.Database.Migrate();
}
```